# What if your question only gets answers after you've avoided/worked around the initial problem?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Say you ask a question (on StackOverflow in my case). And it takes a while before anybody answers. By the time you've got an answer, you've moved on and fixed the problem in a totally different way. I mean, a different way that isn't an answer to the question anymore, because it uses a different underlying technology, ...

How would you best reaction in that case?

- Test the answer(s) anyway? (even though there might not be any time/resources)
- Just leave it open and mention it in the comments? (even though one of the answers might actually be the right one, seems unfair towards the person who answered)
- Delete the question?
- Answer your own question, explaing how you worked around it/avoided the problem, and possibly upvote good answers?
- ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should consider the answers in light of the state of the question at the time that the answers were given.  However, my position might be to still add your own answer.  That way, future readers can have your "an orthogonal method..." response for reference.

Since the other answers are probably more fitting response to the question as it was, it's perhaps appropriate to select one of those as the answer.  Definitely upvote good answers.

I wouldn't delete the question (with all of these great answers you probably wouldn't be able to delete it without the aid of a mod, anyway), especially if it could help someone else.